# Sum of Digits in Product

Tags: arithmetic, contest-math

The question asks to find the sum of digits in the product of:

$11 * 101 * 10,001 * 100,000,001 *10,000,000,000,000,001$.

Now I've somewhat worked out a potential (?) solution with factoring each term to a base 10 binomial:

$(10^1 + 1) * (10^2 + 1) * (10^4 + 1) * (10^8 + 1) * (10^{16} + 1)$.

...Noticing that all exponents were base 2.

i see from the multiplication of the $10^1$ term $ * 10^2$ term produces $10^3 + 10^2 + 10^1 + 1(10^0)$.

Seeing that the degree was determined by multiplying the two leading terms, would it be correct to assume that would happen for $(10^3 + 10^2...) * (10^4 + 1) = 10^7 + 10^6 + 10^5...$ ?

And would this pattern carry on all the way to the last binomial, where i would multiply all those base 10s in the five binomials to get $10^{31} + 10^{30}$ going all the way down?

And thus the product would be 32 ones and have a digitsum of 32?

Method seems too weird and thus sketchy for me. Any other potential *concrete* solutions?

Comment: Is the first number $10$ or $11$? In your first line you write $10$ but in bracket form you write $10+1$.

Comment: Should the first factor be $11$ rather than $10$?

Comment: 11. thank you for pointing the error.

Comment: You don't have to assume it. The result $(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)\cdots(1+x^{2^k}) = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots + x^{2^{k+1}-1}$ (for you $x=10$) can be proven using induction.

Answer (score 2):

Since each positive integer can be written as a sum of powers of $2$  in exactly one way, when expanded out you get the sum of $32$ different powers of $10$, from $10^0$ to $10^{31}$.
So the result is $\sum_{j=0}^{31} 10^j = 11111111111111111111111111111111$.

Comment: Still don't get it... how did you get from sum of powers of 2 to sum of powers of 10????

Comment: It's a sum of powers of $10$ to sums of powers of $2$.
$$\prod_{j=0}^k (10^{2^j}+1) = \sum_{n=0}^{2^{k+1}-1} 10^n$$
since each of these $n$ is a sum of powers of $2$ (its binary expansion).